# Prever dirección en secuencia pseudo-aleatoria basada en umbral 49

Tags: javascript, python, c#, pandas, numpy

Estoy trabajando con una secuencia de números pseudo-aleatorios en Python, representada por la lista 'secuencia', la cual contiene valores de entre 0 al 99:

```py
secuencia = [43, 43, 31, 49, 52, 54, 81, 14, 0, 29, 97, 89, 42, 93, 83, 63, 68, 83, 19]
```

El objetivo es desarrollar un sistema en Python que pueda prever la dirección del próximo número en la secuencia (basado en todos los registros conocidos). La **dirección** se define de la siguiente manera:

1. Si el próximo número es menor que 49, se considera una dirección hacia la izquierda.
2. Si el próximo número es mayor que 49, se considera una dirección hacia la derecha.

Es importante destacar que no estoy interesado en predecir el próximo número de la secuencia en sí, sino la dirección en la que estaría posicionado en relación con el umbral de 49 (la mitad del rango 0-99).

En la implementación de este sistema se puede proponer cualquier enfoque, desde Machine Learning hasta métodos matemáticos avanzados. El objetivo principal es lograr una efectividad y precisión en las predicciones de dirección del 97% al 100%, es decir un sistema altamente confiable que no solo pueda prever la dirección, sino que lo haga con un alto grado de acertividad.

*NOTA: Hago mención en Python porque es un lenguaje muy robusto y popular, pero tambien se está abierto a implementaciones en cualquier otro lenguaje de programación.*

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque consiste en un encargo de código, lo cual no coincide con la tematica del sitio.

Comment: Te recomiendo mirar [Cómo hacer una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y hacer el [Recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). Entre otras cosas, te falta proporcionar más detalles como qué has intentado o cuando dices "1. Si el próximo número ...", el próximo número a cuál?. Aparte, no creo que haga falta utilizar Machine Learning para trabajar este ejercicio

Comment: Si tienes un array con secuencias, que es lo que hay que prever?? no entiendo

Answer (score 1):

He utilizado el lenguaje javascript para realizar este ejercicio.
Estoy retornando un listado de true o false según sea derecha o izquierda la dirección.

```
<script>
    const secuencia = [43, 43, 31, 49, 52, 54, 81, 14, 0, 29, 97, 89, 42, 93, 83, 63, 68, 83, 19]
    console.log(secuencia.map((a)=>{if(a<=49){return false}else{return true}}))
</script>
```